# Retrofit2 singleton Instance

Tags: android, networking, retrofit2

I am trying to create singleton instance for Retrofit2 which works fine. But as soon as I want to dynamic header I am unable to do so.

```
public class ApiManager {


    public final static String BASE_URL = "URL";



    private static ApiManager instance =null;
    private ApiModule apiModule;

    public interface ApiModule {


        @GET("exists")
        Call<ServerStatus> checkExistsTeamName(@Path("teamName") String teamName);


    }


    private ApiManager(){
        final TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        try {
            client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws
                        IOException {

                    Request original = chain.request();
                    Request request = original.newBuilder()
                            .header("X-API-Version", "1")
                            .header("X-USER-TIMEZONE", tz.getID())
                            .method(original.method(), original.body())
                            .build();


                    return chain.proceed(request);

                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        client.interceptors().add(interceptor);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();

        apiModule = retrofit.create(ApiModule.class);
    }





    public static ApiManager getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new ApiManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }




    public ApiModule getService() {
        return apiModule;
    }

    public ApiModule getService(String token){
        return apiModule;
    }




}
```

And in the other activity I can get call to retrofit as.

ApiManager apiManager = ApiManager.getInstance();
apiManager.getService().checkExistsTeamName("parameters")

Which works fine here But want if I want to add extra additional dynamic headers how should I do it?? I am stuck here

Comment: What do you mean by adding extra dynamic headers? Are you looking to add these in the code `original.newBuilder()`?

Comment: Do you mean by adding extra headers to a specific API call?

Comment: Yes I mean to add extra headers to specific APi Call @Emm

Comment: check out @jickson 's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some kind of dependency injection. Try this code. Before you call your service, call

```
ApiManager.setHeaders(map of headers);
```

with header values. Call with empty map or null to exclude them.

```
public class ApiManager {
    public final static String BASE_URL = "URL";
    private static ApiManager instance =null;
    private ApiModule apiModule;

    public interface ApiModule {
       @GET("exists")
       Call<ServerStatus> checkExistsTeamName(@Path("teamName") String 
       teamName);
    }

private static Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();

public static void setHeaders(Map<String, String> headers) {
    ApiManager.headers = headers;
}

private ApiManager(){
    final TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    try {
        client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws
                    IOException {

                Request original = chain.request();
                Request.Builder builder = original.newBuilder()
                        .header("X-API-Version", "1")
                        .header("X-USER-TIMEZONE", tz.getID())
                        .method(original.method(), original.body());

                if(headers != null) {
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
                        builder.header(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                    }
                }

                Request request = builder.build();

                return chain.proceed(request);

            }
        });
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
    client.interceptors().add(interceptor);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();

    apiModule = retrofit.create(ApiModule.class);
}





public static ApiManager getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new ApiManager();
    }
    return instance;
}




public ApiModule getService() {
    return apiModule;
}

public ApiModule getService(String token){
    return apiModule;
}


}
```

Comment: but should I have any header functionality @svatOpluk??

Comment: Tried your way but it doesn't works for me and the application crashes

Answer (score 0):

As per the retrofit [documentation](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) if you want to add headers to specific requests, you can do so as below.

> You can set static headers for a method using the @Headers annotation.
>
> ```
> @Headers("Cache-Control: max-age=640000")
> @GET("widget/list")
> Call<List<Widget>> widgetList();
>
> @Headers({
>     "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.full+json",
>     "User-Agent: Retrofit-Sample-App"
> })
> @GET("users/{username}")
> Call<User> getUser(@Path("username") String username);
> ```
>
> Note that headers do not overwrite each other. All headers with the
>   same name will be included in the request.
>
> A request Header can be updated dynamically using the @Header
>   annotation. A corresponding parameter must be provided to the @Header.
>   If the value is null, the header will be omitted. Otherwise, toString
>   will be called on the value, and the result used.
>
> ```
> @GET("user")
> Call<User> getUser(@Header("Authorization") String authorization)
> ```
>
> Headers that need to be added to every request can be specified using
>   an OkHttp [interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors).

Comment: FYI, from 2.1.0 HeaderMap annotation is added if we have multiple dynamic header params. https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-210-2016-06-15

Comment: @Jickson,@Emma This doesnt solve the purpose I have to write header in each and every request thats tedious and i guess not the right way to do

Comment: You should use OkHttp interceptor if you want to use same headers for multiple requests. Refer this https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-add-custom-request-header

Comment: @Jickson If you see my code above I am doing the exactly the same. Need to find out a way to use as a singleton

Comment: @Jickson Anyways solved the issue through different way. Thanks for assisting :)